# Elastic search: exact match query on string array

Tags: elasticsearch

Given this document:

```
{"name": "Perfect Sunny-Side Up Eggs","ingredientList": ["canola oil","eggs"]}
```

How can I build a query in elastic search to return exact matches on a string array given query term "oil eggs", so far this it what I have, but it returns other irrelevant documents:

```
POST /recipes/recipe/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "ingredientList": {
            "query": [
               "oil",
               "eggs"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

for instance, this document is returned but it doesn't contain "oil". Results should only contain "oil" and "eggs":

```
{"name": "Quick Baked French Toast","ingredientList": ["butter","cinnamon raisin bread","eggs"]}
```

Comment: You need a `bool` query with multiple `Must` clauses: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query will look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ingredientList": "oil"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "ingredientList": "eggs"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Gives me the results:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "ingredients",
      "_type" : "recipe",
      "_id" : "AVeprXFrNutW6yNguPqp",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "name" : "Perfect Sunny-Side Up Eggs",
        "ingredientList" : [ "canola oil", "eggs" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, I know this was posted a long time ago but I'm trying to do something similar, except in my case it should contain the exact phrase "oil" and not "canola oil". Do you know how to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: @tomfl Hi, I'm looking for the same thing, did you resolve it?

Comment: @Vladimir Hmm if I remember correctly I had to change the analyzer to `keyword` : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html

Comment: to make `"oil"` not match on `"canola oil"`, then say `"term": {
            "ingredientList.keyword": "oil"
          }`

Answer (score 3):

Elastic dont have API to exact match array. But same can be achieved using two methods:

1. Using multiple must blocks (not preferred)
2. Using [`terms set`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) query and `script`

   ```
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "terms_set": {
              "ingredientList": {
                "terms": ingredients,
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                  "source": "Math.min(params.num_terms, {})".format(len(ingredients))
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "inline": "doc['ingredientList'].length == params.list_length",
                "lang": "painless",
                "params": {
                  "list_length": len(ingredients)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   ```